# I cannot understand this list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [x+y for x in ['Python ','C '] for y in ['Language','Programming']]
print(a)
```

the output is `['Python Language', 'Python Programming', 'C Language', 'C Programming']`

I thought that two list added together should be like `['Python ','C ','Language','Programming']`

Comment: The for loops are nested. Google for 'Nested Loops in Programming'.

Comment: The output is correct. What you had thought was apparently wrong. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Simply "deconstruct" the comprehension from left to right, it is the same as nesting `for` loops to give you the Cartesian product of the two lists:

```py
a = []
for x in ['Python ','C ']:
    for y in ['Language','Programming']:
        a.append(x+y)
# ['Python Language', 'Python Programming', 'C Language', 'C Programming']
```

What you had in mind as expected output is the result of a list concatenation like

```py
a = ['Python ','C '] + ['Language','Programming']
# ['Python ', 'C ', 'Language', 'Programming']
```